# Creating Nodes in Neo4j with 3d Coordinates

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a file with following details
File Name - NodesNew.csv

```
Node_id,x,y,z
N1,-64.4099,-7.1637,-1502.5
N2,-55.3361,0.635342,-1502.5
N3,-55.3361,0.635342,-1502.5
N4,-55.3361,0.635342,-1502.5
N5,-55.3361,0.635342,-1502.5
N6,-57.0687,-8.17777,-1502.5
N7,-73.8723,-2.5789,-1502.5
N8,1,5,70
N9,1,5,70
N10,-20.2929,-3.26937,-1502.5
```

Now i want to create these Nodes such that, they are placed as per their coordinates in the Graph Database.
I researched and used Spatial functions for the same but things are not working as expected.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///NodesNew.csv" AS row
CREATE (n:Nodes)
SET n = row
RETURN n
```

With this Query, 10 Nodes are created with all the information present in the file. However, for some reason - i want these nodes to be located as per their x,y,z coordinates. Have a look at the screenshot

[image: Nodes]

The nodes that are labelled have same coordinates but then also they are separated.
Please if anyone can guide me as how to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

The Neo4j browser does not place nodes based on x,y,z coordinates.

Take a look at this blog post: https://medium.com/neo4j/visualizing-graphs-in-3d-with-webgl-9adaaff6fe43